# Select rows with specific number of corresponding integer values in a string in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

```
  trans_date                   trans_descr              response_code
1 04-Jan-2018 11:31:15 PM    Acct Trsf:17799788baliek     0
2 04-Jan-2018 11:37:38 PM    Acct Trsf:17800157baliot     0
3 01-Jan-2018 09:46:00 AM    TEST/L17699470bajczy         0
4 01-Jan-2018 09:49:08 AM    TEST/L17699581bajd31         0
5 01-Jan-2018 09:49:08 AM    scartlarydart                0
6 04-Jan-2018 11:37:38 PM    larybarydart                 0
```

Here I want to select rows that contain **`trans_descr`** with corresponding 8 integer values in it. So the result of my query should select rows **`1,2,3,4`**. I hope my question is clear. 
My rights to run this are limited to the select permission.

Comment: See about regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx) to filter out the data.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE trans_descr REGEXP '[0-9]{8,}';
```

`trans_descr REGEXP '[0-9]{8,}'` will filter out all the rows of data where the `trans_descr` contains at least 8 consecutive digits.